# Excel 2010 : Copy block of cells from sheet 2 > sheet1 based on criteria

Tags: vba, excel

Good morning...

I'm trying to perform the following in excel 2010:

Search Sheet1, col A for the 'test a' or 'test b' etc. If say 'test a' is found, then search Sheet 2, col A for all occurrences of 'test a' and copy sheet 2 col B->P for each row into Sheet 1 Col B starting from where the initial 'test a' found in sheet 1, incrementing downwards for each row found in sheet 2.

Sheet 1 :

col A :

- test a
- xxxxxx
- xxxxx
- xxxx
- test b
- xxxxxx
- xxxxx
- xxxx
- test c
- xxxxxx
- xxxxx
- xxxx

Sheet 2 :

Col A, B, C, D, -> Col P

- test a , 1, 2, 3, 4 ....
- test a , 5, 6, 7, 8 ....
- test a , a, b, c, d ....
- test a , e, f, g, h ....
- test b , 1, 2, 3, 4 ....
- test b , 5, 6, 7, 8 ....
- test b , a, b, c, d ....
- test b , e, f, g, h ....

etc

Desired Result :

- test a , 1, 2, 3, 4 ...
- xxxxxx , 5, 6, 7, 8 ....
- xxxxx  , a, b, c, d ....
- xxxx   , e, f, g, h ....

Having never done any excel/vb coding I'm struggling to even get started!.

The best I can do is a high level code:

```
For search criteria 'test a|test b ..'
 if sheet 1, col A equal to 'criteria' (save row where found)
   if sheet2, col A equal to 'criteria'
     copy sheet2, col b->col p, row (where 'criteria' found) > sheet1, Col B, row (where criteria found in sheet1), incrementing row downwards as we go.
```

Very much appreciate some guidance on how to accomplish this!

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a rough sketch that should get you started. Uses a nested loop structure, so it's not too efficient, but provides the basic functionality and should allow you to customize to fit your data better.

```vb
Sub SearchCriteria()

Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Set ws1 = Sheet1

Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Set ws2 = Sheet2

Dim ws1RowCounter As Integer
ws1RowCounter = 2

Dim ws2RowCounter As Integer
ws2RowCounter = 2

Dim innerCounter As Integer
innerCounter = 0

Dim ws1Select As String
Dim ws2Select As String

Dim copyRange As Range

Do While ws1.Cells(ws1RowCounter, 1) <> ""

    'look for this value in ws2
    ws1Select = ws1.Cells(ws1RowCounter, 1)

    'loop through ws2 range, look for matches
    Do While ws2.Cells(ws2RowCounter, 1) <> ""
        ws2Select = ws2.Cells(ws2RowCounter, 1)

        If InStr(ws1Select, ws2Select) > 0 Then
            'copy range if match found
            Set copyRange = Range(ws2.Cells(ws2RowCounter, 2), ws2.Cells(ws2RowCounter, 16))
            copyRange.copy
            Set copyRange = Range(ws1.Cells(ws1RowCounter + innerCounter, 2), _
                ws1.Cells(ws1RowCounter + innerCounter, 16))
            copyRange.PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
            innerCounter = innerCounter + 1
        End If

        ws2RowCounter = ws2RowCounter + 1

    Loop

    ws1RowCounter = ws1RowCounter + 1
    ws2RowCounter = 1
    innerCounter = 0
Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Ben, many thanks for the above, it gave me the leg up I needed! Having never coded in VB this was a learning curve!. Your example worked well apart from these parts : Set copyRange = Range(ws2.Cells(.... , I eventually got working with Set copyRange = ws2.Range(ws2.Cells(...